# what is at() method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

`Array.prototype.at()`

what is .at() method in JavaScript?

```
const myList = ['index0', 'index1', 'index2']

myList.at(1) // 'index1'
mylist.at(-1) // 'index2'
```

there are many methods in js that similarly do this, why using this new method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are similar ways to get an element from an array or string, but at() will use a clear and easy syntax to get this.

> give an index and return value

the principle is easy, just put your desire index and get value, if there isn't a value at this index, it returns `undefined`

for examples:

```
const myList = ['index0', 'index1', 'index2']

// to get latest item in the list using common ways:
const latestItem = myList[ myList.length - 1]

// using simpler approach with at()
const latestItem = myList.at(-1)
```

> similarly, at() method will work fine with strings.

- at the writing time of this post, at() will not be supported by some browser, you can find this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at).
- you can use [polyfill](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#relative-indexing-method) if you want to use at() method in your codebase.

Comment: _"...will not be supported by some browser"_ - Because it's still only a proposal (Stage 4  since some days), https://github.com/tc39/proposal-relative-indexing-method

Comment: thanks for adding perfect details @Andreas